# How to update share point online site collections using funtion app

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I'm using azure function to develop some features about creating site collections.My steps as below:

1. using admin to create site collections(by clientid and client secret)
2. get the new URl client context to update some informations such as group members site owners etc

I'm now facing a problem that firstly I use use account and password to get the new client context and then update site property but now can not use it cause the new corporation policy.
How can i improve this method to fix this issue?

```
public ClientContext GetClientContextByCredential(SharePointOnlineCredentials cred, bool tryNewSite)
        {
            ClientContext ctx = ContextInit;
            try
            {
                ctx.Credentials = cred;
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web, w => w.Url);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                return ctx;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ctx = null;
                if (_logHelper != null)
                {
                    if (tryNewSite)
                    {
                        _logHelper.writeLog(ex.Message, TraceLevel.Info, ex);
                    }
                    else
                        _logHelper.writeLog(ex.Message, TraceLevel.Error, ex);
                }
                return ctx;
            }
        }
```

such error will happer when use `SharePointOnlineCredentials`

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Comment: You can try to create Azure AD application, use the application to get access token then connect SharePoint with the token. For more details, please refer to https://www.paitgroup.com/blog/sharepoint-azure-functions-and-visual-studio-part-2

Comment: Does it means that clientsecret I created in azure AD is not needed?I tried to created AAD and give full control for sharepint,then use clientid and clientsecret to get the context.403 error code will happen.

Comment: Could you please tell me which action you get 403 error?

Comment: just use clientid and clientsecret from AAD to get context.The source is :auth.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(ContextInit.Url, appId, clientSecret);

Comment: If you want to use ```GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext``` to create context, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

Comment: thanks,here I want to access sharepoint via AAD application

Comment: If you want to access SharePoint via AAD application, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

Comment: You need to create AD application and upload certificate(cer or pem file) for the application. Then we can use ````AuthenticationManager.GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext``` to create context with the application client id and certificate.

Comment: I think this will be helpful,I will have a try

Comment: I see, can I use AAD application client secret to get the context?

Comment: No. We cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Azure AD application to connect SharePoint online, please refer to the following steps

1. Create an Azure AD application

```
Connect-AzureAD 

# Create the self signed cert if you have the cert, please skip it
$currentDate = Get-Date
$endDate  = $currentDate.AddYears(1)
$notAfter  = $endDate.AddYears(1)
$pwd  = "<password>"
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName com.foo.bar -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $notAfter).Thumbprint
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my\$thumb" -FilePath c:\temp\examplecert.pfx -Password $pwd

# Load the certificate
$cert  = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("C:\temp\examplecert.pfx", $pwd)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())


# Create the Azure Active Directory Application
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "test123" -IdentifierUris "https://test123"
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $application.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "Test123" -StartDate $currentDate -EndDate $endDate -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $keyValue
```

2. Configure permissions via Azure Portal
   [image]
3. Upload cert to Azure key vault

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "123" -AsPlainText -Force
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "ContosoKV01" -Name "ImportCert01" -FilePath "C:\temp\examplecert.pfx" -Password $Password
```

4. Configure Azure function

   a. [Configure MSI for function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=azure%2Factive-directory%2Fmanaged-identities-azure-resources%2Fcontext%2Fmsi-context&tabs=dotnet#adding-a-system-assigned-identity)
   [image]
   [image]

   b. Create an [access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#key-vault-access-policies) in Key Vault for the application identity you created earlier. Enable the "Get" secret permission on this policy.

   c. code

   ```
   public ClientContext GetClientContextByCredential()
         {
             ClientContext ctx = ContextInit;
             try
             {
                  ctx  = new AuthenticationManager().GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(
         siteUrl,
         ApplicationId,
         tenant + ".onmicrosoft.com",
         GetKeyVaultCertificate("kv-spo", "AzureAutomationSPOAccess")))
         {
         ctx  .Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
         ctx  .ExecuteQuery();

                 return ctx;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 ctx = null;
                 if (_logHelper != null)
                 {
                     if (tryNewSite)
                     {
                         _logHelper.writeLog(ex.Message, TraceLevel.Info, ex);
                     }
                     else
                         _logHelper.writeLog(ex.Message, TraceLevel.Error, ex);
                 }
                 return ctx;
             }
         }

    internal static X509Certificate2 GetKeyVaultCertificate(string keyvaultName, string name)
   {


         var serviceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var  keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(serviceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));


     // Getting the certificate
     var secret = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://" + keyvaultName + ".vault.azure.net/", name);

     // Returning the certificate
     return new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Result.Value));


   }
   ```

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/richard_dizeregas_blog/performing-app-only-operations-on-sharepoint-online-through-azure-ad

Comment: I was confused with the step how to get keyvaultclient,even in my console test code,I could get the cetificate also.Not in azure funtion.

Comment: @element8763 Regarding the issue, please refer to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-azure-key-vault/

Comment: @element8763 Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: So far no more issues,I'm not using azure add applciation for keyvault.Do it means I have to use Identities to get certificate in funtions app?here I got a problem that how can i debug at local?

Comment: In Azure function, you can use Identities or ad application to get certificate  from key vault. Regarding how to debug, please refer to https://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Remote-Debugging-Azure-Functions-V2-The-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-No-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-document

Comment: I solved this issue as in visualstudio Tools-Options-Azure Service Authentication(I think it is just like msi endpoint in local),yesterday I used my dev account,so It works well (your code above about get secret using manage identity),but I changed my account later.It failed today,that the issue I worked today.Any way,it is another issue.Thanks a lot,and I put accepted on your answer